# Style a custom WPF control when it's in a different state

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, styles

I have a custom autocomplete control in WPF.It's created by combining a textbox and a dropdownlist, and a custom style for it.Looks like this ->"
[image]

The background color he has is the same even if is editable or readonly.And on my view i have more boxes and lists, they look like this ->

[image]

These are simple textboxes, and they change they're background depending on they're state: readonly or editable.

So my question is : how can i style my custom control to have that same gray background when it is in readonly mode in order to have the same standard on my view ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use DataTrigger to get it works, like this:

```
<Style TargetType="YourCustomControl">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="ColorHere"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="False">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="ColorHere"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

Comment: It was a bit more difficult , but I've pulled it out , thanks for the answer tough